# NSERC (canadian institution) asks for Times New roman, can I use another font?

Tags: ethics, application, funding, writing, canada

I need to write an outline of my research for a grant. The orginization I am applying to, NSERC asks for:

"Body text in a minimum 12 pt Times New Roman font"

Well here's a little problem, I don't own Windows and getting my hands on an MS product to write the proposal irks me a bit. I also don't like the idea that people's taxes are being used to promote a proprietary font. NSERC should ask for an open font, such as Liberation Serif.

In short, can I use another font or must I really use a microsoft product to type this proposal?

As a general answer to those thinking this is silly/non-important. The font times new roman is a proprietary font, meaning it requires quite a bit of effort to access it on systems that have don;t have a license for it (I am in such a system, so this is already affecting me).

But moreover, this is a *public* grant. This is effectively pushing people towards using proprietary software for research (or in this case to apply for research grants) and that is not ok when there are perfectly valid free fonts that achieve the same result.

NSERC does NOT give away free money, NSERC collects funds from taxes and reinverts them into research. It is not ok for a *public* organization to favour *proprietary* tools when free tools that achieve the exact same purpose exist. It literally disenfranchizes individuals.

Imagine if instead of a proprietary font, the grant process demanded that you submite a docx file or another, similar, proprietary file format. This would essentially be NSERC promoting MS software which would be, by definition, a corruption of academic incentives. This matters, it is not the most important issue in the world, but it matters.

Comment: Times New Roman is not owned by Microsoft and is available on MacOS and probably other non-Microsoft software. Also, expecting that your government only use your tax money in ways that you approve of is a tad unrealistic (especially when you have chosen this bizarre issue as the hill to die on).

Comment: Anyway, you can use whatever font you like… and NSERC can shower free money on whomever it, in turn, likes. Presumably they will choose from the many applicants who don’t disqualify themselves right away by blatantly ignoring the grant writing guide’s instructions.

Comment: Anyway #2: if your computer truly does not have access to Times New Roman, you can always email the grant program director to explain the issue and ask if you can use another font. I’m betting they wouldn’t mind.

Comment: @DanRomik This. But you should've written an answer.

Comment: Didn't Microsoft release this font for free a long time ago? Something about "core web fonts"?

Comment: As others have said, if you're using Mac OS you should already have access to Times New Roman. If you are using an Ubuntu derivative, [apparently you can get Times New Roman for free in LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-get-times-new-roman-font-in-libreoffice-on-linux/5539). I'm obviously not going to check every linux distribution, but I bet you can find it on most of them if you look.

Comment: This post feels more like a rant than a question meant for genuine feedback.

Comment: Unless the system blocks a submission, I would be surprised if any reviewers notice you use a Times New Roman clone such as Nimbus Roman. If you're using LaTeX, you might check out the New TX Font package.

Comment: My guess is that "Times New Roman" is there only to prevent you from using some horizontally squished (but still 12 pt vertically) font to cheat some page limits (and drive reviewers crazy).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Or to prevent people from using a font like Comic Sans.

Comment: @AndreasBlass if that is the reason, it is ignorance in the purest form: better to set a limit on words/characters, rather than enforcing an indirect minimal width on the characters that will fill the page(s), as it is now with the hard requirement on font.

Comment: On linux, install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` with your favorite package manager.

Comment: @henning OP doesn't have a technical problem here, they have an ethical problem.

Comment: @Federico Poloni oh, I see. I wouldn't die on that hill, to be honest.

Comment: What do you mean by "disenfranchise"? I don't see how it takes a way a legal right to anything.

Comment: Research is meant to be accessible, by demanding the use of proprietary software you push away people that for economic, ideological or personal reasons do not have direct access the proprietary tool or refuse to support the organization that holds the copy right.

Basically it puts you in a position where you either support the copy right holder or you are blocked from funding.

Comment: @Makogan - 'Basically it puts you in a position where you either support the copy right holder or you are blocked from funding'- is not at all the case here, as so many technical solutions indicate. I suspect the answers would be different if the context was different. Many who may support your larger point may find themselves unable to align on this issue, precisely because it is not binding.

Comment: We are in 2021, we have been to the moon (well, we = westerners) and the concept that free \neq open is still missing in the eyes of many (and we are in SE:Academia !).
Since we live in a world described by physics law, and physics prescribes that there is no energy conversion without loss, there ain't no such thing as a free lunch.
If a proprietary tool is given to you for free, **you** are paying for it.

Comment: Microsoft has no ownership rights to this font. It has a license only. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman

Comment: The question: _can I use another font?_ is specific to the NSERC. Also, this question borders on a rant. Hence my vote to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, there is a free software alternative to Times New Roman that is *metrically compatible*, available as part of the [Liberation Fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts). Using it has the advantage that the letters consume exactly the same amount of space as they would for Times New Roman.

This leaves you two choices to handle the issue:

- Ask the funding body if they permit you to use this *same letter size* font. Since the role of the rule is likely to be limiting the size of proposals, this is a reasonable request.
- Finish your proposal and ask a colleague with a Windows or Mac PC to convert your document to PDF for you after changing the font to Times New Roman. This should not affect the layout of the document.

The second approach has the problem that if your colleague opens your document in a different program (e.g., MS Word instead of LibreOffice), the layout may be modified.

On a related note, if using Microsoft OneDrive is an option for you (e.g., when your point is not about using non-free software at all but really only about the cost of the font), you can write your document with the online version of MS Word there with a free account and select Times New Roman. When you download a copy in PDF, the font is not actually embedded, but the PDF should still work and be shown with that font on computers having it installed.

Answer (score 8):

As has been pointed out by several others, the font is readily available on non-Microsoft products. You aren't the first to face problems with this; luckily plenty of people have come up with [solutions](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/681gfi/is_a_school_legally_allowed_to_force_you_to_use/).

There is no serious technical difficulty here. On the ethical front, I think [Hanlon's razor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) is helpful here. The organisation most likely chose the simplest instruction that they could come up with which served a large group of people (most people, in their perception). Since it seems to work, they probably saw no reason to update it. They may have a point- a large number of people in my vicinity do think of TNR as a default font. Is it universal, or a clear best choice? Certainly not, and there is no universal choice.

If you want to correct the situation for the greater good, first get the grant (following their requirements) and then write to them. If you want to solve your immediate, individual problem, use one of the proposed workarounds. Doing anything else is unproductive.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question, because Times New Roman is a propriertary font (albeit free on many operative systems).

This is a bad question, because the only possible answer is "ask NSERC".

However, I am quite sure that if they had time to put such a non-sensical constraint, they will have time to answer questions about the same constraint (I am not sure about their opening to allow for exceptions, though).

Final note: if the requirement is "one page, written at minimum with Times New Roman 12pt" is to avoid people cramping tons of text with a thinner font, it is absolutely idiotic. One (I mean one as NSERC) should just fill a page of text Times New Roman 12pt, count the characters (or the words) and then ask for such a limit.

Comment: That is not exactly correct. The format also allows for tables and images. So if you used say 2k words with images and tables then it would not be the same as 2k words without images. It’s a strict format ( e.g NSERC DG grants are 5 pages and that’s it) and it is sometimes annoying, but the flexibility of being able to add as many images and tables as you want makes up for it.

Comment: I removed some unkind comments; let us remember our [code of conduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/conduct). In particular: "Be inclusive and respectful. Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online....If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on."